# UITableViewDiffableDataSource in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uikit

Here is my implementation of UITableViewDiffableDataSource in Objective C. My datasource parameter is currently defined in the header.

I was hoping to use the UITableView's DataSource property directly rather than a datasource parameter, but keep receiving a warning about it being a weak parameter that will be released.

Any thoughts on how this should be implemented to avoid that? The UITableView property is defined as Strong.

```
_dataSource = [[UITableViewDiffableDataSource alloc] initWithTableView:_tableView cellProvider:^UITableViewCell *(UITableView *table, NSIndexPath *indexPath, User *user) {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = user.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.email;

    return cell;
}];

[_tableView setDataSource:_dataSource];
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Im unable to find anything about DiffableDataSource and ObjC